# NullInjectorError: No provider for JwtHelperService

Tags: json, angular, typescript, jwt, guard

I'm in Angular 5.

First: `npm install @auth0/angular-jwt --save`

Then I import it: `import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';`

**This is my authentication service:**

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    console.log (localStorage['token']);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // Check wheter the token is expired and return true or false
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
}
```

**And this is my Guard service**

```
export class GuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log ('bye');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
    console.log ('Welcome');
    return true;
  }

}
```

**There is a token in the localstorage:**

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImFjMTUyNzZhZjA2MjU1YTdlMDM0MmQ5ODg4N2M1ZmI2ZWNmM2RlNGUyNjhmYTc4MTliODRhOTVmMmJiNGZiMTliMDFkNjBhNWRlNjhlN2VlIn0.eyJhdWQiOiJmMDExY2M1OC00MGNlLTQzYTktOGY3MS04NDI0OTRlM2E5OTciLCJqdGkiOiJhYzE1Mjc2YWYwNjI1NWE3ZTAzNDJkOTg4ODdjNWZiNmVjZjNkZTRlMjY4ZmE3ODE5Yjg0YTk1ZjJiYjRmYjE5YjAxZDYwYTVkZTY4ZTdlZSIsImlhdCI6MTUyMzI5NzkzNSwibmJmIjoxNTIzMjk3OTM1LCJleHAiOjE1MjMyOTgyMzUsInN1YiI6IjIiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCIsImFuZ3VkcnUiXX0.RNY2Yb9xiJDcER4rtHEAYMmoLyvPYij-upZc97q-mSgICKE6_xWih_IBjY4cHQXkkiRyCXaqCfwfMM4YWVjv7bsMlLN5bWlH0JTeYoYf2gENLBIG51NwGpU3iAl8KG_51ljZKbs3RE_ULDbphM1NG8BhobVQ5RlObWzejrkPcMHqlGJaMOMLQuXC1iBR2jI9tlfiP4RD4FUUsRkUEUJ5PSIRl34jWoTv31SSf1bkv43q3YeKTfk6pXZ5Ft_eV8G871KkmQSHANAn26A5ujj2FOh-uCV_VNJ97RuTQ6J4NP2YB-mMaWYpZ1xF-4ndqafRGFXJ_8euBO4cA36zvP3B7g
```

**And this is the error:**

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> JwtHelperService]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthService -> JwtHelperService]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for JwtHelperService!
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> JwtHelperService]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthService -> JwtHelperService]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for JwtHelperService!
>     at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
>     at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>     at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
>     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
>     at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>     at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
>     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
>     at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
>     at _createClass (core.js:10891)
>     at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10865)
>     at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
>     at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>     at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
>     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
>     at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>     at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
>     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
>     at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
>     at _createClass (core.js:10891)
>     at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10865)
>     at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>     at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>     at eval (zone.js:873)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>     at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>     at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
> ```

Also, it shows me the route, but without the array from the service...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `JwtModule` provided by the `@auth0/angular-jwt`, which will add `JwtHelperService` to the providers, or you need to add it manually to the modules provider.

Something like

```
const JWT_Module_Options: JwtModuleOptions = {
    config: {
        tokenGetter: yourTokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: yourWhitelistedDomains
    }
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        JwtModule.forRoot(JWT_Module_Options)
    ],
...
```

Fore more see [**Documentation**](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)

Comment: Yes, it is preferable to use in the top module

Answer (score 66):

A little late to the party, but I ran into the same issue trying to follow the standalone docs and what it doesn't cover is the need to import the options InjectionToken which is referenced in the constructor of the service:

```
import { JwtHelperService, JWT_OPTIONS  } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

...

providers: [
        { provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS },
        JwtHelperService
    ]
```

Comment: are these going into `app.module.ts`?

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This problem occurs because you have not added JWTmodule to imports in app.module.ts

```
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem("access_token");
}

JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        allowedDomains: ["example.com"],
        disallowedRoutes: ["http://example.com/examplebadroute/"],
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, if all you want to use `JwtHelper` for is decoding, like in this case checking if the token is expired, then you can use this.

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    // Check if the token is expired and return true or false
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
}
```

Source: [Documentation](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#usage-standalone)

Answer (score 3):

I battled with this issue as well. I found a workaround:

## Test configuration

In your `modulename.spec.ts` make sure that you configure a provider for the `JwtHelperService` (In my case it was `AuthGuard.spec.ts`):

```js
import { TestBed, inject, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { JwtModule, JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

let jwtHelper: JwtHelperService;
const testBedConfiguration = {
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({ // for JwtHelperService
      config: {
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return '';
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    JwtHelperService
  ]
}

describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(testBedConfiguration);
    jwtHelper = TestBed.get(JwtHelperService);
  });

  it('should ...', inject([AuthGuard], (guard: AuthGuard) => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

This solved my issue, but since my implementation was in my auth service which is used by my authguard for the routes, I have to include that config in every single page I have protected by the authguard.

Answer (score 2):

If you used  **@auth0/angular-jwt** to get the jwt assistance and used dependency injection to access the module it is necessary to  import jwt module to the app.module.ts or what ever the module you used.moreover you have more privileges to configure your module importers with disallowed domains, allowed domains , header name,  custom factory functions etc.

```
import { JwtModule } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem("access_token");
}

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // ...
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
       tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
      allowedDomains: ["localhost:3001", "foo.com", "bar.com"]
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

if you don't want to inject it, you can instantiate.

```
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";

const helper = new JwtHelperService();

const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(myRawToken);
const expirationDate = helper.getTokenExpirationDate(myRawToken);
const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution which worked for me is declaring constant variable type of "JwtHelperService" instead of declaring it in a constructor.

```
 const helper = new JwtHelperService ();
```

Now use helper services with helper constant

```
 return !helper.isTokenExpired(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ngModule add in providers this :

```
providers: [JwtHelperService,{ provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS },],
```

so this will be imported :

```
import { JwtHelperService, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

in your component just import like this :

```
import { JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { JwtModule, JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();

```
constructor(
private http: Http,
) { }
     decodeToken() {
         const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
         return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
     }
```

this fixed my problem
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/482#issuecomment-569251938

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issues by changing my import from :

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

to

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwthelper.service';
```

Comment: This is a non standard and so not recommended practice