# Decode firebase/php-jwt in Angular 6

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6, lumen, php-jwt

I am using **firebase/php-jwt** in my **Backend Api (Using Lumen)** to serve **Authentication Token**.
and I am using **Angular 6 in Frontend**.

This is my result from backend **after logged in** : -

```
{
"message": "Successfully Authenticated !",
"status": "Found",
"code": 200,
"data": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJsdW1lbi1qd3QiLCJzdWIiOjEsImlhdCI6MTUzMzgxNjc3OCwiZXhwIjoxNTMzODIwMzc4fQ.84BaTHYoWPEzNsZ6Qu0YK-VQelN0WQ0gcmUdXsxO7OA"
}
```

My **Payload structure** for this token is :-

```
$payload = [
        'iss' => "lumen-jwt", // Issuer of the token
        'sub' => $user->user_id, // Subject of the token
        'iat' => time(), // Time when JWT was issued.
        'exp' => time() + (60*60) // Expiration time
    ];
```

So, When I am decoding it I just decode with : -

```
JWT::encode($payload, env('JWT_SECRET')); // In environment file "JWT_SECRET={random_secret_code}"
```

So, I have a **constant JWT_SECRET** which I am using.

**My Question is in which algorithms the token is generating ? because I have not
specifying any algorithm in the encode() function?**

**Now In Angular how can I extract by decoding the token to get user_id, expiration time and other informations ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token was signed with the `HS256` algorithm, which is probably configured as the default algorithm in PHP-JWT. You can get that information just by pasting your token into the https://jwt.io online debugger.

The header looks like this:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

In Angular, you can use the package jwt-decode:

Install it with: `npm install --save jwt-decode`

and use it like this:

```java-script
var decode = require('jwt-decode');

var token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJsdW1lbi1qd3QiLCJzdWIiOjEsImlhdCI6MTUzMzgxNjc3OCwiZXhwIjoxNTMzODIwMzc4fQ.84BaTHYoWPEzNsZ6Qu0YK-VQelN0WQ0gcmUdXsxO7OA"
const tokenPayload = decode(token);

console.log(tokenPayload.exp) // read the expiration time
```

Comment: your answer really helped me a lot for understanding through only the algorithm part. Thanks for that.

Along with your usage example is quite understandable but this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075688/how-to-decode-the-jwt-encoded-token-payload-on-client-side-in-angular-5

helped me to get the correct usage for angular, just to let you know.